# A good aproach on sorting recycler view after update and some doubts

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, kotlin

I am having problems sorting items inside the recycler view after updating them.

I found this approach that is looking terrible and im wondering if there is a better approach. Also im using it to add new records to the recycler view but im not sure if it's a good practice of if I should change it.

Another big doubt I have in my code is about how im handling things in the adapter

Is it possible or better to do the sorting through the view holder ?

I really appreciate any help or suggestions you can provide.

Aproach:

Calling function on main activity to do the folowing

```
MyList.clear()
MyList.addAll( dbHandler!!.cursor())
MyList.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.sortervalue }))
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

How im handling buttons, is it a good practice or a big no ?

inside the `onBindViewHolder`

```
p0.itemView.editButton.setOnClickListener {
    editpress()
    Log.d("myTag", "edit pressed")
}
```

Comment: You can take button click reference in activity or Fragment (When click part need to calculate many of things such as send data throw View model or Database operations etc).

And second things is that. Sort the list. Take a reference of list which is showing in adapter. When you add item in list just sort it instead of clear. then notify

Comment: If you are using SQLite  sort your items in the function  that queries them and call that function whenever you what to update it

Comment: Fahadi Muhumuza , is it a good idead to call a cursor whenever I update something ? Not better doing the intent as I proposed ? This way I just sort the list in the main activity and I just add one line to the database, the cursor will only be called on create.

Comment: Tariqul Islam, i tried manipulating the list in the adapter but nothing happens, i think the list declared in the main activity "val adapter = Padapter (mylist)" is what controls the view holders and then an intent would be inevitable to change the list in the main activity not the adapter. Is there another way ?  I did the clear because the update happens inside the adapter, i would also need an intent instead of the clear to add the line in the main activity list that is controling the adapter and the notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by moving the list entirely to the adapter so i dont call the adapter giving the list like

in Main activity it was :
private val adapter = adapter (list)

instead i do like this now :
private val adapter = adapter ()
and in main activity on create

adapter.lista.addAll( dbHandler!!.cursor())

so the list is inside the adapter only now when i sort it i dont have to pass it to adapter again. 
to sort it :
listaPrioridades.sortByDescending { it.xxxx }

where xxxx is the column you are sorting.